# Using different termination types on CAN bus

Tags: can, bus, termination, split

Is it possible to terminate one end of a CAN bus using Standard termination (single 120 ohm resistor across CANH and CANL) and the other end using Split termination (two 60 ohm in series with a capacitor between their joint and ground)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Split termination is an enhancement on simple termination. It should appear identical to a properly balanced differential signal.